# Flutter Googlemaps error when opening new route

Tags: flutter

I have BottomNavigationBar using IndexedStack so that my googleMaps wont reload when changing page. In page one I have a button and on page two I have googleMaps. When I push the button I want the page to change to page two and then to call function in there. For example to zoom to new location.

I'm using scoped model to handle my state.

I have already figured out a way to change the page, but I'm not sure what to do with the GoogleMapsController. I lifted it to ScopedModel class, but now I'm getting error when opening new route and closing it and then trying to change push the button to go to a location on the map:

```
I/flutter ( 8784): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8784): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 8784): The method 'animateCamera' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 8784): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 8784): Tried calling: animateCamera(Instance of 'CameraUpdate')
I/flutter ( 8784): 
I/flutter ( 8784): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8784): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 8784): #1      AppStateModel.goToMapLocation 
package:restapoints/state/app_state.dart:57
I/flutter ( 8784): #2      RestaurantInfoPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
package:restapoints/pages/restaurant_page.dart:56
I/flutter ( 8784): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:507
I/flutter ( 8784): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:562
I/flutter ( 8784): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:102
I/flutter ( 8784): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:242
I/flutter ( 8784): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:204
I/flutter ( 8784): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:156
I/flutter ( 8784): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:184
I/flutter ( 8784): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:158
I/flutter ( 8784): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:138
I/flutter ( 8784): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:101
I/flutter ( 8784): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:85
I/flutter ( 8784): #14     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
I/flutter ( 8784): #15     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
I/flutter ( 8784): 
I/flutter ( 8784): Handler: onTap
I/flutter ( 8784): Recognizer:
I/flutter ( 8784):   TapGestureRecognizer#5de3a(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: ready, won arena, finalPosition:
I/flutter ( 8784):   Offset(320.8, 298.5), sent tap down)
I/flutter ( 8784): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[read about initState()](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#3-initstate)

This is the first method called when the widget is created, it must be `StatefullWidget`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // You can call your zooom to new location function here
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't give clear enought information, updated the post now though.

Answer (score 0):

This error was resolved by moving the ScopedModel to the top of Widget tree:

```
  AppStateModel model = AppStateModel();
      runApp(
    ScopedModel<AppStateModel>(
      model: model,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

So for anybody having trouble with googlemaps reloading in tabNav, use Indexed stack and wrap all the pages to Navigator. Then lift GooglemapsController to ScopedModel and put the ScopedModel(or any other state management model) to the root of your application.